# BMW E90 2007, passenger side heating is not working

Tags: bmw, e90

I got a problem with my BMW E90 2007. The Driver side heating is working properly, the hot air comes through vents without issues.

The problem is with the passenger side, the vents are open, but there is no hot air there. The air is neutral, maybe little cold. Nothing change even if I put max heating.

The coolant level is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the BWM have zoned automatic climate control?

Comment: Yes, my BMW has zone climate control

Comment: You most likely have a stuck blend door, which would mean the blend door motor is bad. You'd have to find it, pull it out, and test it to see if it's at issue.